# NodeJS: node-gyp compile with the equivalent gcc -lm option

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I'm new in developing nodejs addons in C++.

I have a static c lib that I include in my addon, the lib is needed to talk to a custom hardware, but some functions of this library uses math.h. So when I compile in a C example I do: `gcc main.c libmackrnp6_0_2_fPIC.a -o test -lm`, no problem there, but when I include this lib in the cpp addon I have a problem with the pow function.

How can I compile the addon `sudo node-gyp configure build` with the -lm option (gcc equivalent)?

**binding.gyp**

```
{
   "targets": [
       {
           "target_name": "octotuner",

           "sources": [
                "params.cpp",
                "headerv6.h"
            ],
            "libraries": ["/home/nvidia/webrf/api/libmackrnp6_0_2_fPIC.a"],
            "link_settings": {
               "libraries": [
                  "-lm"
               ]
            },
       }
   ]
}
```

**params.cpp**

```
#include <node.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" {
    #include "headerV6.h"
}

using namespace v8;
using namespace std;

void getParams(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();

    int status = 0, numplaca = 0;
    unsigned char json[9999] = ""; //<-- the lib function needs this (I know)
    unsigned char flagTuner = 0;
    int timeOut = 20; //segundos

    parametros(json, flagTuner, numplaca, timeOut, &status); // <-- this uses pow

    std::string sJson(reinterpret_cast<char*>(json));

    Local<String> retval = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, sJson.c_str());
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(retval);
}

void Initialize(Local<Object> exports) {
   NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "getRF", getParams);
}

NODE_MODULE(octotuner, Initialize);
```

**teste.js**

```
const rf = require('./build/Release/octotuner');
console.log(rf.getRF())
```

**Testing**

```
sudo node teste.js
```

**Output:**

```
{
        "Numero_da_Placa":0,
        "Comando_OK":1,
        "Tuner0":{
                "Canal_Fisico":25,
                "QUALIDADE_LA":"-",
                "QUALIDADE_LB":"-",
                "QUALIDADE_LC":"-",
                "BER_LA":"-",
                "BER_LB":"-",
                "BER_LC":"-",
                "Potencia":-1.95,
                "SNR":3.9,
                "Modo":"8K",
                "Intervalo_de_Guarda":"1/8",
                "Modulacao_LA":"QPSK",
                "Taxa_do_Codigo_LA":"2/3",
                "Entrelacamento_LA":400,
                "Segmentos_LA":1,
                "Modulacao_LB":"64-QAM",
                "Taxa_do_Codigo_LB":"3/4",
                "Entrelacamento_LB":200,
                "Segmentos_LB":3,
                "Modulacao_LC":"Error",
                "Taxa_do_Codigo_LC":"Error",
                "Entrelacamento_LC":"Error",
                "Segmentos_LC":"Error"
        }
}
```

**C program that uses the same library (not in addon, just for testing):**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "headerV6.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int i = 0, status = 0, numplaca = 0;
    char json[9999] = {0};
    unsigned char flagTuner = 0;
    int timeOut = 20; //segundos

    parametros(json, flagTuner, numplaca, timeOut, &status);

    printf("%s", json);

    return 0;
}
```

**Compiled with:** `gcc params.c libmackrnp6_0_2_fPIC.a -o teste`

**Compile FAIL** (*that's why I think the problem with the addon is that it's not linking math lib*)

```
(metadados.o): na função `recoverDataNum':
metadados.c:(.text+0x138): referência indefinida para `pow'
metadados.c:(.text+0x1d8): referência indefinida para `pow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Compiled with:** `gcc params.c libmackrnp6_0_2_fPIC.a -o teste -lm`

**Compile OK**

**Testing:**
`sudo ./teste`

```
{
        "Numero_da_Placa":0,
        "Comando_OK":1,
        "Tuner0":{
                "Canal_Fisico":25,
                "QUALIDADE_LA":100.0,
                "QUALIDADE_LB":100.0,
                "QUALIDADE_LC":"-",
                "BER_LA":0.0000e+00,
                "BER_LB":0.0000e+00,
                "BER_LC":"-",
                "Potencia":-19.50,
                "SNR":37.9,
                "Modo":"8K",
                "Intervalo_de_Guarda":"1/8",
                "Modulacao_LA":"QPSK",
                "Taxa_do_Codigo_LA":"2/3",
                "Entrelacamento_LA":400,
                "Segmentos_LA":1,
                "Modulacao_LB":"64-QAM",
                "Taxa_do_Codigo_LB":"3/4",
                "Entrelacamento_LB":200,
                "Segmentos_LB":12,
                "Modulacao_LC":"-",
                "Taxa_do_Codigo_LC":"-",
                "Entrelacamento_LC":"-",
                "Segmentos_LC":"-"
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `"link_settings": {"libraries": ["-lm"]}`? (from https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1296)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, yes, it doesn't work

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting and how do you produce it? If you are building a static library (a `.a` on Linux), it won't include the math library within. Traditionally, that is dynamically linked, though you could statically link it into an exe, `.so`, or even sneakily into your `.a` if you try hard enough.

Comment: I will update with the result

Comment: @metal take a look plz, I've edited the question

Comment: Right. You're building a static library. This doesn't pull in all the symbols it needs from `libm.so` into itself. When you try to build the exe, it fails because it also does not find the symbols until you tell the linker where they are located with `-lm`. Adding that is the proper way to create an exe needing the `pow` symbol. How does it fail from nodejs? I don't know nodejs, but you *probably* want to build a shared library, not a static library. That's the way most plugin architectures work.

Comment: I don't know if you've had a look at https://stackabuse.com/how-to-create-c-cpp-addons-in-node/ but they seem to describe how to use libmath as a shared library

Comment: I just have the static lib, the `node-gyp configure build` works, the addon is working, but the json output is different from the c example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Solved**

I've used the following `binding.gyp` and I've got a new version of the thirdy part library and it's working now! Thanks.

```
{
   "targets": [
       {
           "target_name": "octotuner",
           "sources": [
                "params.cpp"
            ],
            "include_dirs": [
                "./so"
            ],
            "link_settings": {
                 "libraries": ["/home/nvidia/webrf/api/so/libmackrnp6_0_2_fPIC.a","-lm"],
            }
       }
   ]
}
```